# Would you recommend LearningTree for ASP.net training?

Tags: asp.net

I am a Windows app developer (drivers, fat client, etc) and did mostly C and C++ for the past 15 years. Now that I got laid off, everyone I applied to is asking about ASP.net. I looked through a few books and played around but I need some formal training. Hopefully something inexpensive b/c i am unemployed for 1 year now.

Is $2K+ for Learning Tree worth it? Any other suggestions?

Comment: Also take a look at (duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602728/most-popular-classroom-bootcamp-or-online-training-for-asp-net-3-5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before spending any big bucks, I would work through the tutorials on http://www.asp.net.  They have a great set of training materials.  If you need a 'class', how about https://www.microsoftelearning.com/ or other remote training, which would be cheaper.  If at the end of these you still need more, take a on-site class and you will at least have a good idea of what you want to learn.

I have not taken any LearningTree classes, but I have taken other blitz classes that can be beneficial, but you will need to use it or lose it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I'll look at the links you posted.